# Django EmailMessage send() works and then gives HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have two forms on my clients site; one on the homepage and one on the contact page.  I will test the forms one minute and they work fine and then I'll test again at later and I get  `HTTP Error 400: Bad Request` - its driving me nuts because I can't figure it out.  I disable one of the forms to troubleshoot, but that did nothing.  Below are my forms; please tell me I am missing something obvious :)

**Form Template**

```
<form action="" role="form" method="post" id="contactForm"> 
  {% csrf_token %} 
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-color-out btn-block" type="submit">Send Message</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Contact View**

```
def contact(request):
    form_class = ContactForm

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_class(data=request.POST)
        messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Thank you, your message was received.')

        if form.is_valid():
            fullname = request.POST.get('fullname', '')
            phone_number = request.POST.get('phone_number', '')
            email_address = request.POST.get('email_address', '')
            message_content = request.POST.get('message_content', '')
            subject = 'Contact Information Submitted from Trust and Beneficiary Advocates'
            from_email = settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
            recipient_list = ['kfritz@*****.com', 'charles@*****.com']
            ctx = {
                'title': 'Contact Us',
                'subject1': subject,
                'fullname': fullname,
                'phone_number': phone_number,
                'email_address': email_address,
                'message_content': message_content
            }

            message = get_template('email_forms/contact_form_email.html').render(Context(ctx))
            msg = EmailMessage(subject, message, from_email=from_email, to=[email_address], bcc=recipient_list)
            msg.content_subtype = 'html'
            msg.send()

            return redirect('/thank-you/')
    return render(request, 'pages/contact.html', {
        'form': form_class, 'title': 'Contact Us'
    })
```

**Index(Home) View**

```
def index(request):
    form_class = FooterForm

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_class(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            fullname = request.POST.get('fullname', '')
            phone_number = request.POST.get('phone_number', '')
            email_address = request.POST.get('email_address', '')
            message_content = request.POST.get('message_content', '')
            subject = 'Contact Information Submitted from Trust and Beneficiary Advocates'
            from_email = settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
            recipient_list = ['kfritz@***.com', 'charles@***.com']
            ctx = {
                'title': 'Trust and Beneficiary Advocates',
                'subject': subject,
                'fullname': fullname,
                'phone_number': phone_number,
                'email_address': email_address,
                'message_content': message_content
            }

            message = get_template('email_forms/contact_form_email.html').render(Context(ctx))
            msg = EmailMessage(subject, message, from_email=from_email, to=[email_address], bcc=recipient_list)
            msg.content_subtype = 'html'
            msg.send()

            return redirect('/thank-you/')

    return render(request, 'pages/index.html', {
        'form': form_class, 'title': 'Trust and Beneficiary Advocates'
    })
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are both views (homepage and contact page) using the same form/contact view?

Also, you probably shouldn't add a message to the request until after you validate the form (and send email).

Comment: No, they have different views.  I've updated my post with the other view.  And, you're probably right about the message - guess I wasn't paying attention :)

Comment: @StudioRooster My first guess is that there is something wrong in your ALLOWED_HOSTS settings in settings.py file. And please also check if this URL **redirect('/thank-you/')** actually exists in your urls.py or not.

Comment: @StudioRooster Are you using amazon aws for mail sending?? The problem is in ALLOWED_HOSTS settings.

Comment: I am using sendgrid, like I always have I will check my allowed hosts settings to confirm.

Comment: @PrakharTrivedi I changed my allowed hosts to `['*']` just to be sure and the first form worked but then I got a bad request on the second one.  Then I realized that I used an email address in the second form test that is one of the `recipient` emails.  When I retested with another email address, it worked great.  So the allowed hosts was probably a good call, and I am not worried about the bad request because of my email, but do have any clue why this would be an issue?  Thank you.

Comment: @StudioRooster You should use **msg.send(fail_silently = True)** to send mail without failing to send mail to a bogus or invalid email id.

Comment: @PrakharTrivedi thank you for that answer - I have done the same mistake with the email, almost lost my mind where is the bug :), I do not need to set msg.send(fail_silently = True), I have it false and it is working - I am doing it via class based views and using EmailMultiAlternatives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **msg.send(fail_silently = True)** to send emails without failing to send mail to a bogus or invalid email id.

For both views with email sending functionality,use it like this :

```
message = get_template('...../email_template.html').render(Context(ctx))
msg = EmailMessage(subject, message, from_email=from_email, to=[email_address], bcc=recipient_list)
msg.content_subtype = 'html'
msg.send(fail_silently = True)
```